# How to use Suppliers.memoize when method throws Checked-Exception

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I'm trying to use `Suppliers#memorize` on a function that throws `IOException`

Snippet:

```
private Supplier<Map> m_config = Suppliers.memoize(this:toConfiguration);
```

This gives an exception:
    Unhandled exception type IOException

so I had to do something like this:

```
public ClassConstructor() throws IOException
{
   m_config = Suppliers.memoize(() -> {
   try
   {
     return toConfiguration(getInputFileName()));
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
 });

 if(m_Configuration == null) {
   throw new IOException("Failed to handle configuration");
 }
}
```

I would like the CTOR to forward the `IOException` to the caller.
The proposed solution is not so clean, is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Use [`UncheckedIOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html)

You're tagging [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), so you should use the `UncheckedIOException` which is present for this very use case.

```
/**
 * @throws java.io.UncheckedIOException if an IOException occurred.
 */
Configuration toConfiguration(String fileName) {
  try {
    // read configuration
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new java.io.UncheckedIOException(e);
  }
}
```

Then, you can write:

```
m_config = Suppliers.memoize(() -> toConfiguration(getInputFileName()));
```

Comment: I was using something like: IllegalArgumentException

Comment: @Shvalb Well if somehow you used `RuntimeException`, that would have been better, but since `UncheckedIOException` exists, that's the one you should use now.